# Can the ajax url option take an array of urls instead of just one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

How do I fetch data from an array of json urls and store their contents in an array

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    urls = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1RsiDuydBBHyu4OBjlxq1YH6yT3qcJDMB6-YKU-xxd_k/od6/public/basic?hl=en_US&alt=json","https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1Pk4KnjBtYsIJF65ZQFEdBLqPufPK-HSFqhZvmxjZD_E/od6/public/basic?hl=en_US&alt=json"];
    local = {};
       $.ajax({
          url: urls,
          cache: false,
          context: local,
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
          }

       });
    </script>
```

The console.log method does not return any data and it does not return an error. How do I obtain data from the 2 urls I've used

Comment: That isn't how ajax works. If you need to send the same data to different urls, then you'll need an ajax request for each url. That being said, if you are also building out the back-end, then there might be a better way to do it by leaving the data manipulation in the back-end instead of sending over the same data to numerous routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery doesn't have an overload for this by default, but you can achieve the same thing using promises and performing one AJAX request for each URL in the array:

```
var urls = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1RsiDuydBBHyu4OBjlxq1YH6yT3qcJDMB6-YKU-xxd_k/od6/public/basic?hl=en_US&alt=json","https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1Pk4KnjBtYsIJF65ZQFEdBLqPufPK-HSFqhZvmxjZD_E/od6/public/basic?hl=en_US&alt=json"];
var $deferredArray = $.map(urls, function(url) {
       console.log("here");
       return $.ajax({
              url: url,
              cache: false,
              success: function(data){
                console.log("Success");
              }
       });
    });
$.when.apply($, $deferredArray).then(function() {
    console.log('All done');
});
```

Comment: -1 for incorrect `All done` - the promise resolves as soon as the function passed to `when` exists.

Comment: @Bergi Stupid internet tutorials leading me down the wrong path. I must find time to read books :(

Comment: I've updated the answer, but really it's just the same as Andy's now.

Comment: Well, it uses `map` instead of a loop, which makes it better :-)

Answer (score 4):

No.

The array will be converted to a string, which won't be any of the URLs that you want, so you'll usually end up with a 404 error (which you won't see because you don't have an error handler (and I think there might be issues with detecting errors on JSONP requests anyway)).

If you want to loop over an array of URLs and make an Ajax request for each one, then you'll have to write the loop yourself, and call `$.ajax` each time you go around it.

You might want to consider using an iterator that you bump in the success function rather than using a simple for loop so that you don't attempt to fire off lots of requests in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$.when.apply`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)* for this. It allows you to pass in an array of promises and run a function when they have both completed. So something like this:

```
var urlArray = [url, url2];
var promises = [];

function returnPromise(url) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    context: local,
    dataType: 'jsonp'
  });
}

// push each promise into your promises array
for (var i = 0, l = urlArray; i < l; i++) {
  promises.push(returnPromise(urlArray[i]));
}

// pass the promises array into $.when
$.when.apply(null, promises).then(function (data1, data2) {
  // do something with the data
});
```

*[`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is available on every JS function and allows you to call it with an array of arguments instead of a list.